# Can I edit a "live" log file?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, log-files, files

I want to mark some log entries for a web server log file. Is it possible to do this while the file, possibly simultaneously, gets new entries added by the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the file, but the entries added to the file while you edit it are lost, because the editor loads the log file into memory, and saves the file from memory to disk after editing.

However, you can move the log file to another file with `mv` command, reload webserver, and then edit the other file. This way no entries are lost. Webserver starts to write to an empty logfile when you reload it.